# API endpoint that depends of the Authenticated user

Tags: api, asp.net-core-webapi, api-design

I have the following entities:

```
public class Company { 
  public Int32 CompanyId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
} 

public class Project { 
  public Int32 ProjectId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
  public virtual Company { get; set; }
} 

public class ProjectUser { 
  public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  public String ProjectId { get; set; }
} 

public class User { 
  public Int32 UserId { get; set; }
  public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to create an Api endpoint to get a Company's Projects:

```
companies/{companyId}/projects
```

This url makes sense but returning projects should be restricted to:

1. Projects, in provided company, where current authenticated user is associated (ProjectUser);

   OR
2. All projects, in provided company, if current authenticated user is system admin.

**Question**

So this request depends on the authenticated user ...

Should I send the UserId in the request and then check its permissions in the API?
If yes, how would the url, e.g. `companies/{companyId}/projects`, become?

Or should I simply get the authenticated User and checks its permissions in the API without sending the UserId in the Request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latter. Your request should be authorized, most likely via sending the `Authorization` header with a previously obtained access token. You should not nor do you need to send the user id along with the request. That would be obtained via the user principal, specifically via the `NameIdentifier` claim. As for your resource-level authorization, you'll use the user id obtained from the principal to ensure that the authenticated user has access to said resource, most normally via a foreign key on the resource itself. The [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.2) have a more extensive guide.